# Docker - curl returned "connection reset"

Tags: networking, docker, boot2docker, portforwarding

I have docker host in a virtual machine.
the host is boot2docker 1.10-rc1.
and a container from a centOS 7.2 image.

I tried to run some application inside the container.
I started the two application and check the network status:

```
[root@564f3e59142b logs]# netstat -lnput
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41656           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      11995/BmtMDProvider
tcp6       0      0 :::44027                :::*                    LISTEN      4405/java
```

both application provides some HTTP service.

when I curl both applications (inside the same container) :

the response of java is OK

```
[root@564f3e59142b logs]# curl 127.0.0.1:44027
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

but on BmtMDProvider I got "connection reset by peer" instantly. This is a HTTP service url and it shouldn't return a "connection reset".

```
[root@564f3e59142b logs]# curl 127.0.0.1:41656
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

the BmtMDProvider is some application from third party (I can't modify it) and works normally on a "real" machine.

Could I have some suggestion ,guide or diagnostic steps to find out where the "connection reset" comes from? Thanks.

Edit: 
BmtMDProvider is a process spawned by java and it have a random port. the may be multiple instances of BmtMDProvider. java access BmtMDProvider by http (they are in same docker container and java got "connection reset", the same as curl)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your container with IPV4 ports, meaning if you are currently running using

`$ docker run -p 41656:41656 BmtMDProvider`

run it as

`$ docker run -p 127.0.0.1:41656:41656 BmtMDProvider`

Comment: Sorry the my question text was not  very clear:  BmtMDProvider is spawned by java , they are in same container. when java ( or curl in container) access BmtMDProvider port, it got connection reset. See my edit :)